# Read noisy data from GPIO

Tags: embedded, gpio, noise-reduction

In an embedded programming project for FreeRTOS/ARM, I attempted to read 24 bits of data on a noise GPIO signal. While idle, the signal has a lot of random noises; during the actual data, the noise is suppressed and only the signal data will be read. The data signal consists of a preamble of 300us HIGH (1) followed by 31x300us LOW (0) and then each bit 1 is a 900us HIGH and 300us LOW and bit 0 is 300us LOW followed by 900us HIGH.

I did measurements using a simple tight GPIO read loop that shows an average 388 reads in 300us.

So I attempted to count my reads, with an epsilon of +/- 15 reads, of HIGH and LOW and determine if I read the preamble or the bits following that using a state machine. But I can't detect any preamble or data. I suspect that additional codes in the real reading codes, even though not too complex, would result in different read frequency compared to the simple measuring loop. What would be the correct way to read such data?

Comment: This entirely depends on the nature of the noise. If it is constant noise, there's not much you can do. Maybe the mean value of all samples would suffice. Or if there are bursts of noise, you should be able to filter it out with a median filter. Another thing you could do is to read the data with an ADC instead. Then you can set more narrow voltage levels for 1s and 0s,  than the standard "TTL levels" where your GPIO port interprets something as 1 or 0. Anyway, I believe you have to provide more details for anyone to be able to answer.

Comment: We don't know the HW and your code. How could we help you?

Comment: It can't work. The reason is that you can't tell a starting 1 from a starting 0. If the first bit is 1, the signal is 300us high, 9300us low, 900us high. If the first bit is 0, the signal is 300us high, 9600us low, 900us high. So you need to be able to measure the difference between 9300us and 9600us. I would suggest a tolerance of +/-100usec for reliable operation. That's 1% accuracy. But +/-15 out of 388 is 3.9%. So if you can measure to within +/-15 out of 388, you aren't even close.

Comment: If there is noise when the line is idle, but not when it is driven, does it need a bias? Like a pull-down resistor (the first preamble is high)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. The method is sound. The problem are

1. even though it is an RTOS, attempt to print debug information on the console during the I/O loop is a no-no, even if very little data are printed; it would quickly disturb the timing. Once I removed the debugging output in the loop, it works correctly.
2. the relative timing between the short and long signals are correct but the exact timing can still vary greatly (even after removing the debug output.) In my case, the short time span can range from 180 to 288 reads.